# This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, uwp

I have installed the Enterprise version of Visual Studio 2017 v 15.8.4 on Windows 7 Professional.  I have downloaded the UWP Samples, when I attempt to load any of the C++ UWP sample solutions such as the Altimeter solution I get the error ..."This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio."  Online I found the suggestion that with a prior version of VS reloading the project worked, but in my case the project is greyed out.  What is the problem?

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/selecting-workloads-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: if you want to do uwp development you need windows 10 for that and not windows 7

Answer (score 2):

From [Visual Studio 2017 Product Family System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs):

> Universal Windows app development, including designing, editing, and debugging, **requires Windows 10**. Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2012 R2 may be used to build Universal Windows apps from the command line.

You need Windows 10 to open UWP samples in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Thanks I thought that might me the case.

Comment: Yes that was it, so the error is misleading, it should say ... you need windows 10!

Comment: @use: The proposed error message would be misleading, too. You *can* build UWP apps on the command line, using Windows Server 2016 or 2012 R2. At any rate, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).